# Large Nested Defaults in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, parameters, arguments

I have code similar to the following:

```
export type Bar = {
    baz: number
};

export type FooConstructorArguments = {
    config: Bar
};

class Foo {
    construction({
        config: {
            baz = 1
        }
    }: FooConstructorArguments) {
        let c = config;
        let b = baz;
    }
}
```

But neither `config` nor `baz` are accessible.  What is the proper way to utilize nested typed argument defaults within `TypeScript`?

Comment: `baz` _is_ accessible. `config` isn't because it was destructured _to_ `baz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`baz` is accessible](https://tsplay.dev/WKy9GN). `config` isn't because it's just part of the destructuring path to `baz`, not a target of the destructuring pattern. If you want *both* `config` and `baz`, you'll need to just pick out `config` in the parameter list, then pick `baz` from it after:

```typescript
class Foo {
    construction({ config }: FooConstructorArguments) {
        const { baz = 1 } = config;
        let c = config;
        let b = baz;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBDKcC8cDeAUHCXAEYYBeAXHAHYCuAtmcFIQL4DchhoksBMlQAxCBADCEOgGcYUBgGMY0AIJQA5s2B0YM3AWKlF0gGYBLDbUztuvRQBsMM-WIiHScE7PlKY56QAKfC8zSzgOWjcpHwVlNU1tXRkASg9PY2k5AnIqAwBGDgNvCw0eDNIHYHhFYrCyowqq+DIDCkpy0g5OIA)

or if you don't really need `baz` and just need `b`:

```typescript
class Foo {
    construction({ config }: FooConstructorArguments) {
        let c = config;
        let b = config.baz ?? 1;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBDKcC8cDeAUHCXAEYYBeAXHAHYCuAtmcFIQL4DchhoksBMlQAxCBADCEOgGcYUBgGMY0AIJQA5s2B0YM3AWKlF0gGYBLDbUztuvRQBsMM-WIiHScE7PlKY56QAKfC8zSzgOWjcpHwVlNU1tXRkASg9PUgdgeEUDbwsNHgzM7PI8sI0AOgpKOAB+OrgARiLSDk4gA)

---

Side note: I've left `construction` in the above in case it's meant to be a method, but suspect you meant `constructor`.